# Power BI- Query Edit

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I am trying to create new measures that will only show the data value of the Last day every month and another measure will show the data value of every week Saturday in Power BI.

Many thanks in Advance.

[image]

The data is continuing and the next series of data will appended data wise

Output:
Need to create a measure which will show only last day of the Week value ( Example- Saturday is my Last of the Week and Count numbers I need to see as output)
Similarly for Month - Last day of the Month I need to see the Numbers of each service.

Comment: Show your example of data and desired result

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Calendar table mark as "Date Table", which is connected by relationship to your Table? If so, then you can use ENDOFMONTH ( 'Calendar'[issue_date] ) to get lastDateOfMonth

then simply:

```
ShowValueAtLastDayOfMonth = 
calculate( sum(Table[Total sale]), 
    KEEPFILTERS( 
    filter(ALL('Calendar'[issue_date]),
        'Calendar'[issue_date] = ENDOFMONTH ( 'Calendar'[issue_date] )
        )
      )
    )



ShowOnlyOnSaturday =
calculate(sum(Table[Total sale]), KEEPFILTERS( FLITER(ALL('Calendar[issue_date]),
WEEKDAY ( SELECTEDVALUE('Calendar'[issue_date])) = 7 )))
```

Without a "Date Table" we need to replace 'Calendar'[issue_date] with your Table[Date] and ENDOFMONTH with:

```
VAR LastDateVisible =
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Table'[Date] ) )
VAR LastYearVisible =
    YEAR ( LastDateVisible )
VAR LastMonthVisible =
    MONTH ( LastDateVisible )
VAR DaysInMonth =
    FILTER (
        ALL ( 'Table'[Date] ),
        YEAR ( 'Table'[Date] ) = LastYearVisible
            && MONTH ( 'Table'[Date] ) = LastMonthVisible
    )
VAR LastDayInMonth =
    MAXX (
        DaysInMonth,
        'Table'[Date]
    )
VAR Result =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( 'Table'[Date] ),
        'Table'[Date] = LastDayInMonth
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

Comment: No - I have a single set of data that I have shared the snapshot-Above mention query needs an additional table. Can you please write the query without additional relationship table name.

Comment: Try with Updated statement;